# How let Scite support a custom syntax highlight template?

Tags: windows, linux, syntax-highlighting, scite

I need to have a syntax highlighter for a language of mine.

I really like Scite, so I was wondering how to support a custom syntax with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SciTE is based on the open source [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) edit control.  The [Scintilla documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html) has two articles that explain how to write a *lexer*, their term for the part of the program that performs syntax highlighting, along with other information necessary use to them.